# How to display ClientIp in logs using Serilog in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, serilog

Project is using .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI.

I am trying to log IP address of the client's device to console. I have installed this package [Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/) v1.2.0 and followed their steps.
In addition to console, there is a table ErrorLog with column [ClientIp] where I would like to log the IP address.
As you can see in the output, both ClientIp and ClientAgent sections are blank.
Am I missing something? Also please verify if the syntax is correct.

Here is my Serilog config from appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
"using": [],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent" ],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
              "outputTemplate": "[{Level:u3} {Timestamp:o}] {ClientIp} {ClientAgent} ({SourceContext}) {Message} {NewLine}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "@l in ['Error', 'Fatal']"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
              "connectionString": "TestDbContext",
              "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
              "batchPostingLimit": 50,
              "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
               "columnOptionsSection": {
                "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate" ],
                "customColumns": [
                  {
                    "ColumnName": "ClientIp",
                    "DataType": "VARCHAR",
                    "AllowNull": true,
                    "DataLength": 50
                    //"NonClusteredIndex": true
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

Output:

```
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.0041535+05:30]   () APP:API service has 
started
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.5737570+05:30]   
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Now listening on: 
"https://localhost:7017"
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.5987755+05:30]   
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Now listening on: 
"http://localhost:5017"
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.6185554+05:30]   
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Application started. Press Ctrl+C to 
shut down.
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.6255005+05:30]   
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Hosting environment: "Development"
[INF 2022-07-11T20:13:49.6305270+05:30]   
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Content root path: "****"
[ERR 2022-07-11T20:14:29.2967601+05:30]   () Testing exception
[ERR 2022-07-11T20:14:29.3735005+05:30]   
(Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware) HTTP "GET" 
"/api/Hospitals" responded 500 in 970.4728 ms
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: So? Your output is in a console window. You can copy from that window and paste it as text in the question, as the answers to the linked question indicate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey got it.

Comment: Did you get an answer to that? I am using the same library on .Net 6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this package [serilog-aspnetcore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/):

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
{
    // Customize the message template
    options.MessageTemplate = "{RemoteIpAddress} {RequestScheme} {RequestHost} {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded {StatusCode} in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms";

    // Emit debug-level events instead of the defaults
    options.GetLevel = (httpContext, elapsed, ex) => LogEventLevel.Debug;

    // Attach additional properties to the request completion event
    options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
    {
        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
        diagnosticContext.Set("RemoteIpAddress", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
    };
});
```

Check on this link, it might help.

[Adding IP logging #38](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/38)

Comment: Note with the above, you do not need the Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo library, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, this code is working fine. Its returning "::1" that is the loopback address in IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this post, the correct answer is briefly mentioned in the README of the project.

[Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/) relies on `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the current HttpContext. The behavior of this interface was changed in .NET Core 2.1  and was no longer injected by default into the services pipeline.

To get the library to work correctly, you must add the following call to your configure services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // ...
}
```

Or when using top-level statements in more recent .NET projects:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `"Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo"` in your using statement (appsettings.json ln 2).

Comment: Tried that too but no luck.